# Running program over windows lockscreen

Tags: windows, lock-screen

I was wondering if there is any way to run any program on top of lock screen, so the pc is still locked but there is some kind of program running with UI, that you can interact with, without having to unlock windows.

Comment: You can run a service but any normal process could not be used.  So what you want isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible.

Windows does not natively support this for security reasons. If you could interact with a program while a Windows session was "locked", then it wouldn't be truly locked in the first place.

I've heard of programs that *try* to make this possible, but I wouldn't touch them with a 10ft pole.

Comment: So It's better if I write my own program to run as lock screen and after interacting is done then lock my pc?

Comment: I guess so. The only lock screen which is going to offer any security is the Windows one.

Can't be bypassed with Ctrl+Alt+Del etc.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to finally get some recognition outside of North Korea for a change.

Answer (score 4):

1. Run `cmd` as an administrator
2. Type the following into command prompt(simply copy and paste it in):

   ```
   REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\sethc.exe" /v Debugger /t REG_SZ /d "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
   ```
3. Press Enter
4. Lock screen and press shift key 5 times continuously. If it does not happen ensure that your sticky keys are enabled

Comment: aka: escalation of privilege, courtesy of sticky keys exploit

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, depending on the version of Windows it must be done differently.

Basically, GINA.DLL is the access method, and although it can be done, and has been done effectively by some good applications, it always feels like a hack to me.

[Courion](http://www.courion.com/products/passwordcourier.html) makes software where you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> to login OR click a <kbd>Reset Password</kbd> button and then change passwords. Its a great application. This is for Windows XP at least, Windows 7 is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

#### Run programs at login screen, approach #1

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but maybe you want to check out my another answer for little help about running normal programs at Windows 7 login screen.

It will just run `cmd` at login screen but it could be any program, there's just one thing to be aware of: program will be run under `SYSTEM` account.

[Manually enter login information in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/423054/132604)

If this looks like what you want to do then you'll just need to start those programs automatically without user interaction that is required on above example.

#### ... #2, ... maybe #3 ... ?

There is other options out there too, it also depend on what version of windows you are running. Maybe take a look at registry and ... Autoruns found from SysInternals suite provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's an old trick that used to work to break into the lockscreen.

Replace utilman.exe with whatever program you need to run.  It won't be admin with the newer versions of windows, thus it no longer works as an exploit, but perhaps it will accomplish what you desire.  Once you overwrite it, just press the button that normally starts the "ease of access center".

Windows probably wont allow you to do replace it, so you may have to do it from a linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for that: [Transparent Screen Lock](https://www.e-motional.com/TScreenLock.html)

or [multi-app kiosk on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1191994)